# So I am trying to ask a question to retrieve a mentioned channel but doesn't work

Tags: discord.js

So I am trying to make my giveaway bot but can't make a create command so the person can add more details about the giveaway! Thus, I need questions but everytime I try it never goes well!

```
    message.channel.send("Please mention the channel you want the giveaway to be in! **e.g #channel**"); 
  try {
    let msgs = await message.channel.awaitMessages(u2=>u2.author.id===message.author.id, { time: 15000, max: 1, errors: ["time"]});
    if(parseInt(msgs.first().content)==mention.channel) {
        const Channel = message.mentions.channels.first();
        await Channel.send("HEY")
    }
    else {
        message.channel.send("You did not mentioned a channel!");
    }
  }catch(e) {
      return message.channel.send("Command Cancel!")
  }
```

It either returns to the `catch(e)` line or `"You did not mentioned a channel!"`!

Comment: How is `mention` defined?

Answer (score 1):

This should be what you want i think. (works with mentioning the channel, providing a channel ID or providing a channel name)

```
message.channel.send("Please mention the channel you want the giveaway to be in! **e.g #channel**"); 

let channel;
let response; 
try {
    response = await message.channel.awaitMessages(msg => msg.author.id === message.author.id, { max: 1, time: 1000*60*3, errors: ['time'] })
} catch {
    return message.channel.send("Command Cancel!")
}
                    

if (response.first().mentions.channels.first()) {
    channel = response.first().mentions.channels.first()
} else if (!isNaN(response.first().content) && message.guild.channels.cache.get(response.first().content)) {
    channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(response.first().content)
} else if (isNaN(response.first().content) && message.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name.toLowerCase() === response.first().content.toLowerCase())) { 
    channel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name.toLowerCase() === response.first().content.toLowerCase())
}


if (channel) {
    await channel.send("HEY")
} else {
    return message.channel.send("You did not mentioned a channel!");
}
```

Comment: Close! But I want it to ask what channel you want to send a message and then they respond by mentioning a channel!

Comment: Bruh, you could have just added that line yourself: message.channel.send("Please mention the channel you want the giveaway to be in! **e.g #channel**"); i edited my answer for you now...
Or idk if you understood that wrong, but MENTIONING the channel IS POSSIBLE with my code...

Comment: Or if you still need help, open a chatroom with me: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/12985179/nicohd105